# Querying a MariaDB table makes JS code out of order

Tags: node.js, mariadb

I'm trying to create an authentication form in Node.js using MariaDB as my database.
I'm trying to query the username and password, but for some reason it seems that the code gets messed up on runtime, here's an example:

```
exports.Authenticate =  
function(username,password)
{
    console.log("debug - 1");
    dbInstance.query('SELECT * FROM useraccounts where Username = :un AND Password = :pw',
    {un:username,pw:password})
    .on(
    'result', 
    function(result) 
    {
        result.on
        (
            'row', 
            function(row) 
            { 
                console.log("debug - 2");
                console.log('Result row: ' + inspect(row));
            }
        );
        result.on
        (
            'error', 
            function(err) { console.log('Result error: ' + inspect(err)); }
        );
        result.on
        (
            'end', 
            function(info) { console.log('Result finished successfully'); }
        );
    }
    ).on
    (
        'end', 
        function()
        { 
            console.log('Done with all results');
        }
    );
    console.log("debug - 3");
    return "DONE";
};
```

The log shows this:

```
debug - 1
debug - 3
debug - 2
```

I'd really appreciate help with this, it's driving me crazy.

UPDATE:
I've found a solution:
Inside the routes function that calls the "Authenticate" function I've added a function for send the response to the client, and sent it as a callback to the Authenticate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database query is asynchronous, so the query function returns immediately. The callback supplied to the query function is then called some time in the future when the database server has responded. This allows for other things to get done while the query is being executed on the server (e.g. handling HTTP requests, reading from disk, or any other I/O). You will find this asynchronous nature throughout node.js and the many modules people have written for node.

Comment: What would be the correct way to handle this situation? thanks!